# Fantasy anime ending with female musicians casting (violinists?) to save the hero’s girl stuck in a black ball force field

Tags: story-identification, anime

Trying to find anime with love story (harem?) which probably came out in last 10-15 years. Probably a magic school type setting.

I believe magic or some tech equivalent is cast in part (maybe the *only* way, maybe just one way) by playing musical instruments.

Hero loves girl. At the end the girl goes rogue and is enclosed in black ball force field floating in midair. A bunch of female musicians perched on a building (maybe all violinists?) casting to penetrate. With their help hero breaks through to save the girl.